# Sharing Node App and Connect's port

Tags: node.js

Is there any way to get Connect to run on the same port as your node app so you can serve up assets using relative or absolute paths?

Right now I have them running on separate ports, which is a pain:

```
var app     = require('http').createServer(handler).listen(81), 
    connect = require('connect');

connect.createServer(
    connect.static(__dirname + '/assets')
).listen(82);
```

Comment: What are you using connect for? The module where you run the server, is supposed to handle everything, containing other modules within it.

Comment: I'm using connect to serve css and js assets.

Comment: And what are you using `http` for? Connect can handle the stuff `http` does. It's kind of you only need connect.

Answer (score 0):

Let connect create the server for you:

```
var connect=require('connect'),
  app=connect.createServer(handler,
    connect.static(__dirname+"/assets"))
    .listen(81);
```

Only other difference is that `handler` now takes a third parameter, `next`, which is a function that `handler` should call if it doesn't want to handle the request itself but rather wants to pass it on to the static handler (or anything else implemented via connect).